# Python modules not importing

Tags: python, module

New to python and I cannot import modules that I have installed via pip.

For instance, I have installed numpy though cannot import it.

I have a feeling from trying to work this out that it is installing to the wrong directory, or I am calling the wrong version.

```
$ which python
```

returns

/usr/bin/python

I am just not sure how to change it so I can access the modules.

Answer (score 0):

First if all, you are installing the packages using `pip`, which means you install it on python 2 by the default configurations.

The issue you are describing can be caused by several problems:

1. If you are working with an IDE like pycharm- your project interpeter might by python 3.x. You should change it to python 2 since you used `pip` and not `pip3`.
2. Some newer versions of pycharm are opening virtual environment by default in new projects. This means that if you install packages outside the virtual environment you will not be able to access them. When opening a project, intended of applying the default settings, change the interpreter to your system interpreter, probably your python2.7 in your case.
3. You are not using an IDE but accecing python from your terminal like so: `python3` instead of `python`.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

From a terminal try:

```
pip install numpy --user
```

This install numpy to your home directory. Sometimes this helps compared with installing it without the '--user' flag.

Then:

```
python
```

Now you have a python command line. Try:

```
import numpy
```

If you don't see any error message, then the install worked. Control-d or typing 'exit()' returns you to your shell.